# Terraform remote-exec fails on vm resource and dhcp assinged IP

Tags: terraform, vsphere

I'm attempting to run a remote-exec provisioner on a vsphere virtual machine resource in which the IP is being assigned through DHCP rather than through a static IP setting on the network adaptor (due to TF issues with Ubuntu 18.04).

I find that when trying to run the "remote-exec" provisioner it fails since it is unable to find the IP address. I've tried several things and am currently attempting to  set the "host" property of the connection object to to "self.default_ip_address" in hopes that it will use the IP address that is being automatically assigned to the VM through DHCP once it connects to my network...Unfortunately I'm still not having any luck getting this to work.

Below is an example of my resource declaration, is there a better method to running remote-exec when using DHCP that I'm just not aware of am missing? I can't even seem to output the IP correctly after everything is built, even if I don't run the provisioner. Thanks for the help!

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm-nginx-2" {
  resource_pool_id = "${data.vsphere_resource_pool.pool.id}"
  name             = "vm-nginx-2"
  datastore_id     = "${data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id}"
  folder           = "${var.vsphere_vm_folder}"

  enable_disk_uuid           = true
  wait_for_guest_net_timeout = 0

  num_cpus  = 2
  memory    = 2048
  guest_id  = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.guest_id}"
  scsi_type = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.scsi_type}"

  #scsi_type = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.scsi_type}"
  network_interface {
    network_id = "${data.vsphere_network.network.id}"
  }

  disk {
    label = "vm-nginx-2-disk"
    size  = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.size}"
  }

  clone {
    template_uuid = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.id}"

    customize {
      timeout = 0

      linux_options {
        host_name = "vm-nginx-2"
        domain    = "adc-corp.com"
      }

      network_interface {}

      ipv4_gateway = "192.168.0.1"
    }
  }
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo apt-get update -y",
      "sudo apt-get install -y nginx"
    ]

    connection {
      host = "${self.default_ip_address}"
      type = "ssh"
      user = "ubuntu"
      private_key = "${file("files/adc-prod.pem")}"
    }
  }  
}



#This also fails to print out an IP
output "vm-nginx-1-ip" {
  value = "${vsphere_virtual_machine.vm-nginx-1.default_ip_address}"
}
```

Comment: According to the doc: "If VMware tools is not running on the virtual machine, or if the VM is powered off, this value will be blank."

Comment: I saw that in the docs and have made sure I have the tools installed on the vm. I still run into the same issue.

Comment: Can you ssh to the VM from the command-line?

Comment: So I did some digging and figured it out. I'll post my answer as I feel others will definitely run into this.

Comment: What was this answer?